# How to shape a CALL in PYMODBUS (Modicon?)

Tags: serial-port, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus, pymodbustcp

i am in a serius battle with a solar inverter right know (INGETEAM 3play) i am connected by TCP / IP.

I need to understand how to shape my call becouse i am not having the answer i want, and also i dont' know how many bits i am waiting for an answer.
**Here is the call i need to do:**

[image: Call and answer]

I am sure that 01 is the ID 03 means Holding Register, so how do i shape the rest (00 00 00 06)??
This is the code:

```
FORMAT = ('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s '
          '%(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
log = logging.getLogger('pymodbus.protocol')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

variables = [0,6,12,18,24,30,36,70,72,74,76,78,342,344]

data = client.read_holding_registers(0, 2, unit=1)
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(data.registers, Endian.Big)
eastron = round(decoder.decode_32bit_float(), 3)
print (eastron)
```

I know i have to play with the client.read_holding_registers, but how?
The documentation goes like this:
[image]

Maybe the fact that is called Modicon is what i am missing?

To sum up the questions:

1. How to shape my call so it matchs the call 01 03 00 00 00 06?
2. Why when i do the call 01 03 00 00 00 06 i get all the answers (year to seconds) shouldn't i just get seconds? (thinking that the 30006 in the pdf stands for the call itself 03 00 00 00 06)
3. How can i log the DEBUG that i get when doing the call? i am doing this in a raspberry and i am not sure that i would be able to see the call like i do on jupyter

example

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - TRANSACTION_COMPLETE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 6
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x1 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x2 0xc4 0xb
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Changing state to IDLE - Last Frame End - 1580425865.276049, Current Time stamp - 1580425955.463177
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV: 0x1 0x3 0x4 0x41 0x60 0x0 0x0 0xee 0x11
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Getting Frame - 0x3 0x4 0x41 0x60 0x0 0x0
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Response[ReadHoldingRegistersResponse: 3]
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame advanced, resetting header!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Adding transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
DEBUG:pymodbus.payload:[16736, 0]
DEBUG:pymodbus.payload:[b'A`', b'\x00\x00']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How to shape my call so it matchs the call 01 03 00 00 00 06?

Decoding this we get:

01 - Unit ID; 1 Byte;  01
03 - Function code; 1 Byte; 0x03 = Read Holding Registers
00 00 - Starting Address; 2 Bytes (big-Endian); Address 0
00 06 - Quantity of Registers; 2 Bytes (big-Endian); Length of 6

This means the above is a request to Unit ID 1 to 'Read Holding Registers' (3) starting at register 0 returning six registers.

To duplicate this using pymodbus you would use `client.read_holding_registers(0, 6, unit=1)`.

> 2. Why when i do the call 01 03 00 00 00 06 i get all the answers (year to seconds) shouldn't i just get seconds? (thinking that the
>      30006 in the pdf stands for the call itself 03 00 00 00 06)

As noted above the request is for six registers (so this includes the full time).

> 3. How can i log the DEBUG that i get when doing the call? i am doing this in a raspberry and i am not sure that i would be able to see the
>      call like i do on jupyter

From your example it looks like you are already generating debug information. As modbus is a [standard](http://www.modbus.org/specs.php) you should not usually need to look at the bytes being sent/received when using a decent library to handle this for you.

Comment: Thanks men! may i ask you one more questions?
The way i decode the document (PDF) is ok? for example this is the output active power: Start addres: 37 | MB Modicon addres: 30038 | Display order: 16 To call this value from the inverter the code should be `client.read_holding_registers(0, 38, unit=1)` it's weird, i am going to test today btw.

Comment: it does registers the 38 things TY dude i don't need more help!